# How to use action to self page

Tags: php, javascript, html

i am trying to insert the values to table through form.

Here is my code which i have used

Code for insert.php

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "tiger", "tiger") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("theaterdb") or die(mysql_error());
// Insert a row of information into the table "language"
mysql_query("INSERT INTO languages (language) VALUES('$_POST[language]') ")
or die(mysql_error());  
echo "Data Inserted!";
?>
```

Html form

```
<html>

    <head></head>

    <body>
        <form action="insert.php" method="post">New Language:
            <input type="text" name="language">
            <input type="submit" value="Create Language">
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

But i dont want to use the insert.php file, instead i want to use the php code in insert.html. i tried using

```
<form action="">
```

and also

```
<form action="#">
```

and

```
<form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
```

but it is not working.

Comment: php code will not work in .html files..better you change insert.html to insert.php and dont give any action in the form.

Comment: Why do you not want to use that file?

Comment: Rename the file type to `php` and insert the php code there. Html files can't run php code, the whole code will be printed just like string.

Comment: you can configure the web server to treat `.html` files as php files.

Comment: Did you insert the PHP code in there? Are the values to connect to the DB correct? Turn errors on. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Try using `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Php code will not run in .html files.

However you can output html in php files.

You could also rewrite your php page to have an html suffix using htaccess

Answer (score 0):

PHP code will not work in `.html` files.. Better you change `insert.html` to `insert.php` and dont give any action in the form.So the self action will be executed and so the form will be submitted to `insert.php` itself.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">New Language:
            <input type="text" name="language">
            <input type="submit" name='save' value="Create Language">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
    // Make a MySQL Connection
    mysql_connect("localhost", "tiger", "tiger") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("theaterdb") or die(mysql_error());
    // Insert a row of information into the table "language"
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO languages (language) VALUES('$_POST[language]') ")
    or die(mysql_error());  
    echo "Data Inserted!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine two files:

You achive .php files like .html with .htaccess

#### For example: form.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "tiger", "tiger") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("theaterdb") or die(mysql_error());
// Insert a row of information into the table "language"
mysql_query("INSERT INTO languages (language) VALUES('$_POST[language]') ") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Data Inserted!";
}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
New Language: <input type="text" name="language">
<input type="submit" value="Create Language">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

either

```
<form>
```

and

```
<form action="">
```

obviously works.